# Git Eclipse how to merge?

Tags: eclipse, git, merge

I have mybranch, somebody changed it on remote. So when I have right click `synchronize-advanced-remote` on project and choose the same branch and then when I resolved conflicts, click on file `marked as merged` or `merge`, eclipse marks file `red`, I believe this is wrong. How to merge conflicts in eclipse git? I worked with svn, but I cant understand the right way of merging in git. Thank you.

Edit: when I try to use `merge` option next time it just shows 'Merge Result: Failed, dirty worktree, file: xxx.java', what does it mean? how to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before merge, you should resolve all conflicts(files will be marked with conflict red arrow after that too), then you commit to your local repo, then right click on project -> Merge. After that you able to push.